# Little questions regarding "tram stop"

Tags: прилагательные, существительные

I'm a beginner and have a question regarding `bus stop` and `tram stop`.

I want to say: `"I'm going to the bus stop/tram stop."` And I would like to use `остановке`.

I know that `остановка` is feminine and I have to form `авто́бусный` to feminine. So far so good for me.

> 1) Я иду на авто́бусная остановка.

But how do I do this with "tram stop"? It is masculine `трамва́й` and therefor I can not use it with `остановка` or can I?

> 2) Я иду на трамва́й остановка.

I'm thanking you in advance for your help!

Comment: Adjective must always match the gender of the corresponding noun ("остановка"). Also you have to use the correct case (accusative).

Answer (score 12):

Apart from putting the adjective into the feminine gender to adjust it to the feminine noun `остановка`, you also have to put the resulting word combination into the Accusative case, because the preposition `на` needs the following noun phrase to be in the Accusative case, if it is about the direction to the place. That is why the correct way to say it is:

> 1) Я иду на авто́бусн**ую** остановк**у**.

As for the tram stop, the corresponding adjective is formed the same way as with the bus:

> авто́бус → авто́бусная
>
> трамва́й → трамва́йная

And naturally, be it a bus or tram stop, the Accusative case is needed after `на`:

> 2) Я иду на трамва́йн**ую** остановк**у**.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use the form `остановке` you need to use preposition `к` and use Dative case:

> Я иду к останов**ке**

In this case `автобусная остановка` becomes `к автобусной остановке`, and `трамвайная остановка` becomes `к трамвайной остановке`:

> 1. Я иду к автобусн**ой** останов**ке**
> 2. Я иду к трамвайн**ой** останов**ке**